# Why canvas inside div has a vertical offset?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

Why `canvas` inside `div` has a vertical offset?
The web inspector does not show any margin or padding for `div` and `canvas`.

```css
.outer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.inner {
  background: coral;
  width: 40px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<canvas class="inner"></canvas>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I found that setting `line-height: 0;` or `display: block;` removes the offset.

If the inner element would be also a `div`, there would be no offset, since `display: block;` is the default for `div` (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.php). The default for `canvas` seems to be `display:inline`.

The offset also disappears, when the canvas height because larger than the line-height.

Comment: those are hacky solution, you have to adjust the alignment by using `vertical-align: top`